# Need to wrap a JavaScript API in C# class library (not a asp.net application)

Tags: javascript, c#, azure-webjobs

I have an NPM JavaScript library that I need to call its API in my C# Class Library.

That means I like to wrap a JavaScript library in a C# class library.

The final application will be deployed into an Azure WebJob. So it needs to run under Azure PaaS. That means I am limited to what I already have in PaaS platform I can't have any special installtion.

Do I have any practical or feasible option?

**Update 1**

Considering a REST API might not be as simple as it looks and it can be an expensive option.

Why? because many JavaScrip API are stateful. Means you instantiate a series fo classes and variables to work with API. Whereas REST is stateless. So there won't be one-to-one REST to API call. A series of use cases scenarios can be implemented in the REST services, not the API calls.

Comment: Without more details its very difficult to answer this question.  Can the JS be hosted in a node web service and called via REST from the C#?  If not, I suppose you could embed a JS engine, like Chakra or V8, in your class library. (google has a ton of info on both options)

Comment: Another option is to transpile the JS into C#.

Comment: @SamAxe REST wrapper is more of a Plab B. Hopefully there is a more integrated option.

Comment: This sounds like it may be [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What does this library do? Are there C# alternatives?

Comment: @AllanXu: Then, to the best of my knowledge, your alternatives are 1.  Transpile the JS into a .NET assembly.  Or 2.  Embed a JS engine like Chakra or V8 into your C# library.   Based on my experience with these two things, I'd lean toward option 2.  I've gotten V8 to work and heard of people getting Chakra to work in .NET.  I've never quite gotten JS to compile to .NET properly.  YMMV.

Comment: @JasonArmstrong: Are you saying since there is no easy answer for this question, it must be an XY problem? This is not a XY problem. It is quite real life. It is safe to assume that there are JavaScript libraries with no C# equivalent.

Comment: I'm saying you're telling us the solution you're looking at. I'm asking what are you really try to accomplish. What is it this JavaScript library does?

Comment: @JasonArmstrong: At this point, I am not looking for case by case assessment. I like to know if this is a possibility. It seems that this is not possible. Wrapping a JavaScript with a C# class library is not possible, or at least it is not feasible. It is important to know. For my specific case, I think I have to change the solution's architecture and build the application in Node.js and .NET is not an option.

Comment: @JasonArmstrong: here is an example since you are insisting, and there are many many more: https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Chatdown

Answer (score -1):

I think the best bet is to build out a REST layer over the NPM library if you want to consume it in C#. Alternatively I would be very surprised if there wasn't something you could use natively in C# which did something similar to what you're trying to leverage from within javascript.

Comment: We have a JavaScript library that is not implemented in C#. We could re-write it in c#, but the cost is high.